# Distraction-free text editor for Ubuntu/Linux, like pyRoom

Tags: linux, text-editor, ubuntu

PyRoom seems to be spottily maintained and only works with Python 2 so I'm looking for a replacement:

- **distraction-free writing, nothing but the text preferably**,
- pleasant or configurable fonts, text size, and colors,
- flat files storage preferred,
- simple to maintain: packaged would be best,
- easy to call in a script with a fresh note/file.

Nothing more really. Even a spellcheker would be more of a distraction than a feature. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

In my default Ubuntu installation 22.04, I can tweak the default TextEdit to look like this (Showing also the "Options" dialog", sorry I've only the German version ):

[image: Minimal TextEdit]

I've disabled the options

- Show line numbers
- Show status bar

Maybe for you also the option "Highlight current line".

For your other request:

#### Other fonts

[image: otherfonts]

#### easy to call in a script with a fresh note/file

Not sure what your usecase is but you could do `gedit anyfile.txt` and it will be opened in the editor:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I use  [Bluefish](https://bluefish.openoffice.nl/index.html) for simple text-editing tasks, say for pasting in the current contents of my clipboard.

Bluefish has a very low startup time and (with plugins) it can be tweaked to do medium-complexity tasks, e.g. sort a text file; include a linter; perform a regex-based search+replace.

It cannot do pretty text formatting or WYSIWYG editing, it resembles more a slim IDE. It can be installed from the Linux repositories.

[image]